# Is it correct to delete indirect pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am still new to C++, so please be kind when answering. 
When it comes to dynamic memory management, many tutorials give an example or similar of below, which often times they are in the same scope.

```
MyClass * pt;
pt = new MyClass[3];
delete[] pt;
```

Which I have a question what if I lost access to the original dynamic allocated variable but only have the address of it. Consider the following

```
int* intP; //Global variable

void SomeFunction()
{
    int* intP2 = new int;
    *intP2 = 10;
    intP = intP2;

    //Some other actions.....and lost access to intP2 when this function ends
}


void SomeOtherFunction()
{
    delete intP; //Valid?
}
```

Comment: one is intP, another one is intP2....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is well-defined: all pointers pointing to the same location in memory are fair game for deletion. In fact, the same mechanism is at work when you construct objects inside a function, which is a reasonably common scenario:

```
MyClass *create(size_t size) {
    MyClass *res = new MyClass[size];
    ... // Do something else
    return res;
}
...
MyClass *array = create(100);
...
delete[] array;
```

Here is what is happening above:

- The result of `new` is assigned to `res`
- The pointer is returned to the caller, while the original variable `res` goes out of scope
- You delete `array` to free memory that was allocated with `new []` and assigned to `res` inside `create()` function.

In situations when another pointer remains accessible, it becomes illegal to dereference the other pointer after deletion, for example:

```
int *data = new int[200];
int *copy = data;
...
delete[] copy;
// At this point it becomes illegal to dereference data[]
```